# honeypot for css disabled

Tags: css, honeypot

I have read that the users who have CSS disabled will see the field with the "display: none", and if we write something like "If you see this, leave this form field blank" for them the bot will read it as well and may avoid it.

I was thinking a way to avoid this problem: just hide the honeypot field with an "ap Div" layer so the user won´t see it and I think it won´t be affected by the css disabled. I would be grateful if someone told me if it would work, if it presents other problems and if anyone knows a better solution

Thanks in advance for your time!!

Toni

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood you, but I think this 'ap Div' you are referring to is Dreamweaver's way of describing a `div` with the `position: absolute;` CSS rule applied to it.

That being the case, if CSS is disabled, then an 'ap Div' will display on the page according to the ordinary flow of the document.

Comment: Thanks as well for your answer!. Yes, I was referring to Dreamweaver, so I see it will be disabled as well by CSS.

Comment: That being the case, could you please mark my answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

To hide a field, use `<input type="hidden" />`. But given that you want to hide the field only from the user, use something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="hEmail" value="" />
<script>
window.onload = function (){
   document.getElementById('hEmail').type = 'hidden';
};
</script>
```

ps. It is recommended to add JavaScript code in included file, not in the body of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. I have read that to make a honeypot field is better not to type="hidden", I guess the bot could know it. May be what you say works because you make it in an indirect way?. About JavaScript I read as well that some people disable it for security reasons so it wouldn´t work for them.

Comment: @Toni, This is why I suggest to use the JavaScript, because initially field is simple text field and bot will don't know that it be changed to `hidden`. As for users with disabled JavaScript, I think you need to show a notice at top of the page and ask to enable JavaScript.

Comment: ok I see. Can it be made the same but with another language instead of Java which is notIsn´t it another language instead of Java

Comment: I send the previous mesaage unfinished, sorry!. @B7ackAnge7z ok I see. Can it be made the same but with another language instead of Java which is less often disabled?, do you recomend any?. Thanks for your answer! Toni

Comment: @Toni **1)** next time, edit your comment (not add new); **2)** Java is not JavaScript. **3)** JavaScript is the single cross-browser language which can be executed client-side. But, for example also you can use a flash form.